# How do I pass arguments in a route when defined in ini files in fatfree framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

In fatfree framework, I am defining the routes in ini files. like:

```
GET|POST /admin/login = controllers\siteadmin\Login->index
GET|POST /admin/login/@action = controllers\siteadmin\Login->@action
```

Now I was wondering how to pass arguments to the functions in this setup. Also how do I set cache and ttl values for each route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .ini file, you can pass all the arguments of the [route()](http://fatfreeframework.com/base#route) method, separated by commas:

```
GET /foo=class->method //ttl=0, kbps=0
GET /foo=class->method,86400 //ttl=86400, kbps=0
GET /foo=class->method,0,56 //ttl=0, kbps=56
```

To pass arguments, use the following syntax:

```
GET /foo/@arg1/@arg2=myClass->myMethod
```

The method will receive the parameters as a 2nd argument:

```
class myClass {
  function myMethod($f3,$params) {
    echo $params['arg1'];
    echo $params['arg2'];
  }
}
```

Concerning the cache, it is set globally, not for each route:

```
[globals]
CACHE=TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to pass custom arguments, not get them from the url? so for `GET /check/admin` I want to trigger a function like `controllers\siteadmin\SomeClass->myFunction('my_custom_hardcoded_argument')`

Comment: You cannot. The only way is to pass URL arguments.

Comment: URL arguments or query parameters.

Comment: Really helpful for passing more than two arguments in route :)